# Activar botón cuando el input tenga texto

Tags: javascript

Quiero activar el boton id 'delete' cuando el input tenga texto y desactivarlo cuando no, esto usando javascript.

```css
#delete{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa texto...">
<button id="delete">Borrar texto</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el evento `keyup` o `input` y evaluar si hay algo cada ves que se presiona una tecla, o el value cambia:

```js
const deleteButton = document.getElementById("delete");
const text = document.getElementById("text");

text.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  deleteButton.style.display = (e.target.value.length) ? 'block' : 'none';
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.value = "";
});
```

```css
#delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa texto...">
<button id="delete">Borrar texto</button>
```